# use-package syntax: how to set-face-attribute?

Tags: helm, use-package

I'm trying to set `helm` using `use-package`. The `set-face-atttribute` doesn't work within `use-package`:

```
(use-package helm-config
      :config
      (progn
        (helm-mode 1)
        ;; other config ...
        (set-face-attribute 'helm-selection nil 
                    :background "purple"
                    :foreground "black")))
```

However, it works well outside the use-package. It is quite neat to put all the config of a specific package together. So how to set face in `use-package`?

Comment: Can you specify *how* it does not work within use-package?

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me like this:

```
(use-package helm
  :ensure t
  :init
  (progn
    (require 'helm-config)
    (helm-mode 1)
    (set-face-attribute 'helm-selection nil
            :background "purple"
            :foreground "black")))
```

Comment: I tested it for several times before I find out the problem: I put `helm` config (using `use-package`) in a separate file, and `load` it in the `init.el`. This doesn't work. I have to put the `use-package` to the `init.el` file. Is there anything I can do if I don't want to put everyting in the `init.el`? `load` is not the right option?

Comment: You ask the wrong person. I have adopted the approach from http://metasandwich.com/2013/01/19/emacs-config-youre-doing-it-wrong/ and put everyting in one file. Then i imenu through the different sections using helm imenu. I feel very comfortable with this approach.

Comment: If you want to improve your emacs startup time by lazy-loading helm, you should change `:init` to `:config` and then add a `:bind` section with a few keys you're most likely to use (I bind `C-x C-f` and `M-x` and a few others). helm is one of the slowest packages for startup, lazy-loading it can have a big impact.